# TV4 JSON Schema array of objects validation

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema, tv4

I would like to validate that a property called "foo" contains an array of "bar" objects.

Using TV4 for validation all works as expected if I use an array as the value of foo however if I specify something other than an array such as a string or an integer validation passes when it should not.

```
var json = { "foo" : { "one" : "bar" }};
```

Passes as expected with a correctly formatted array.

```
var json = { "foo" : { "bar" : "error" }};
```

Fails as expected with in-correct formatted array.

```
var json = { "foo" : 2 };
```

Passes event though foo should be an array.

Below is the full code.

```
var should = require("should");
var validator = require("tv4");

var barSchema = {
    "id": "bar",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties": {
        "one": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["one"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}

var fooSchema = {
    "id" : "foo",
    "title": "foo",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo" : {
            "type:" : "array",
            "items": {"$ref":"bar"}
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "foo"
    ]
}

describe("foo with integer", function() {
    it("should result in an error message", function(){
        var json = {
            "foo" : 2
        }
        validator.addSchema(barSchema);
        var result = validator.validate(json, fooSchema);

        // above should fail but it passes
    });
});
```

Comment: Are there any missing schemas? (`validator.missing`)  If it's a referencing issue, then the schemas it can't find will turn up there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add fooSchema to the validator:

```
describe("foo with integer", function() {
    it("should result in an error message", function(){
        var json = {
            "foo" : 2
        }
        validator.addSchema(barSchema);
        validator.addSchema(fooSchema);
        var result = validator.validate(json, fooSchema);

        // above should fail but it passes
    });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use addSchema for fooSchema as doing a validator.validate which is a tv4 validator adds the schema when it is passed in as a parameter. I tried using the addSchema anyway just incase and it has no impact. It still fails.

Comment: What is the value of result?

Comment: The value of result is true.

Comment: The problem must be in the references. Do you have something in validator.missing property?

Comment: The validator missing property is empty. there are no missing validators. I am going to spend some time today debugging through the t4v library to see if I can notice anything off there.